# Find the static moments about the coordinate axes of a segment of the straight line $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} = 1$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**Task:** Find the static moments about the coordinate axes of a segment of the straight line $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} = 1$

A static moment is defined as $S = \sum_{i} m_i d_i$. It is needed to calculate the centre of mass. The equation can be re-written as $y = b - \frac{b}{a}x$ and we are interested in the area bound by $0 \leq x \leq a$. From what I understand, we need to find a $S_x$ for the x-axis and a $S_y$ for the y-axis.

**x-axis:** $S = \sum_{i} m_i d_i = \int_{0}^{a} y \ dm = \int_{0}^{a} (b-\frac{b}{a}x) \ dm$. If I  know the total mass of the straight line $M$ then I know that $m = \frac{M}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$. By differentiating, I can get $dm =  \frac{M}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} dx$. However, by substituting $dm$ to the integral will provide me with an answer of zero. I am having troubles relating the $dm$ of this problem to $x$. Could someone help with this connection?

Comment: I don't get $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Your mistake is in $$\int_0^a(b-\frac ba x)dx=0$$
You have $$\int_0^ab dx-\frac ba\int_0^axdx=b(a-0)-\frac ba(a^2/2-0)=\frac{ba}2$$

Also, the problem is that the proportionality between $dx$ and $dm$ is not the one in your formula. The length density used in the answer you mentioned is $1$. So if you would integrate to find the mass $$\int_0^a dx=a$$
but the length of the bar is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, so the mass should be $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So what went wrong? You don't integrate for mass along $x$ but along the line $l$. You can write $$dl=dx\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}a$$
You can check now that the total mass is $$\int_0^adx\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}a=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
So $$S_x=\int_0^a\left(b-\frac ba x\right)\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}a dx=\frac b2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
Similarly, you can write for $S_y$ using $$dm=dy\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}b$$

Comment: I understand this mistake, but I fear that the answer looks wrong. I was able to get the answers from someone (not a solution), they were : $S_x = \frac{b}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $S_y = \frac{a}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ The setup of the problem I provided is still wrong.

Comment: I've added the full solution